# Dispositivo Android falha no httpTransportSE e o emulador não

Tags: android, web-service, emulador, webserver

Tenho um servidor com *webservices* a correr localmente.

Quando eu corro a aplicação android no emulador, este consegue-se conectar ao webservice. Quando corro a mesma aplicação num dispositivo real, este não se conecta.

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boas malta.

Após dois dias para descobrir porque é que no emulador dava e no real device não dava, cheguei à solução do problema.

PROBLEMA:
Fiz uma aplicação Android que usava serviços e esses serviços corriam num servidor local.
Quando testava a app no emulador a aplicação corria e os serviços eram chamados, mas quando testava num device, já não conseguia chamar os serviços.

ERRO LANÇADO:
O erro que dava era no httpTransportSE, na função call(SOAP_ACTION, URL) e era um erro de "(No route to host)".

MOTIVO DO PROBLEMA:
Depois de uma investigação sobre qual seria a razão de isto acontecer, conclui que devia-se ao local onde os serviços eram corrido (local do servido - IP) e não um problema de código.
Os serviços estavam a correr localmente, para que a aplicação Android soubesse o local (IP) do servido(serviços), era necessário que estivessem ambos a correr na mesma rede.

SOLUÇÃO:
Fazer um PC de router(criar uma rede) e conectar tanto o servidor(serviços) a essa rede criada como o dispositivo android.

COMO FAZER UM PC DE ROUTER:

1. Abrir o cmd como administrador.
2. Dígitar: netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=Nomedarede key=Senha mode=allow (PARA CRIAR A REDE).
3. netsh wlan start hostednetwork (PARA INICIAR A REDE)

Após estes três passos já irá aparecer a rede criada.

NOTA:

- Se aparecer algum erro no ponto 3, tente usar programas que criem redes. (ex: Connectify Hotspot).
- Se tiverem algum router onde se ligam normalmente para ter acesso à internet, não necessitam de configurar um router num PC.
- Para ver as redes pré-configuradas(abrir cmd como administrador): netsh wlan show profiles
- Caso queiram apagar a rede criada(abrir cmd como administrador): netsh wlan delete profile name="nome_perfil"

Foi o problema e solução que encontrei e deu certo. Obrigado!